# DB2 Reset a Sequence at midnight

Tags: database, db2

So I'm trying to reset a sequence to o everyday at midnight, this is a  procedure I have but I'm lost.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_seq_reset AS
 BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE BRGSEQ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'CREATE SEQUENCE BRGSEQ' ||
  '  MINVALUE 1 ' ||
  '  MAXVALUE 999999 ' ||
  '  START WITH 1 ' ||
  '  INCREMENT BY 1 ' ||
  '  NOCACHE';
```

END;

Comment: You may use a single [ALTER SEQUENCE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-alter-sequence) statement with the `RESTART` clause instead. What's the problem with the routine?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein How do you make it to RESTART the seq at midnight?

Comment: Run the corresponding command with OS cron or Db2 [ATS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=scheduler-administrative-task).

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [Db2 administrative task scheduler](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=scheduler-administrative-task) (ATS) for that.
Enable it on the server from the Db2 command line processor:

```
db2set DB2_ATS_ENABLE=YES
```

Run the following set of statements.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

-- create a sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE DB2ADMIN.BRGSEQ 
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOCACHE
@

-- create a routine for Db2 ATS
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DB2ADMIN.my_seq_reset
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE DB2ADMIN.BRGSEQ RESTART WITH 1';
END@

-- schedule the routine to run at midnight every day
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD
(
  'DB2ADMIN.BRGSEQ sequence reset'
, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
, NULL
, NULL
, '0 0 * * *'
, 'DB2ADMIN'
, 'MY_SEQ_RESET'
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
)@
```